# Pandas loop for take row and add data back

Tags: python, pandas

I started with the below

```
       15/12/2015  15/11/2015  15/10/2015
Stock                                    
AA             10          11          11
BB             20          10           8
CC             30          33          26
DD             40          80          60
```

from there created a boolean:

```
df4 = df['15/12/2015'] < df['15/11/2015']
df5 = df['15/11/2015'] < df['15/10/2015']

Stock
AA     True    False
BB    False    False
CC     True    False
DD     True    False
dtype: bool
```

I now want to add the following data:

```
           15/12/2015  15/11/2015  15/10/2015
Stock                                    
AA              2          11          22
BB              4          14          33
CC              3          12          30
DD              5          16          40
```

to create a list which looks like the below (stock reference, Date, boleen return, reference from last table:

```
stock    Date    
AA       15/12/2015     True      2     
AA       15/11/2015     False     11
BB       15/12/2015     False     4
BB       15/11/2015     False     14
CC.......etc
```

Comment: Can you show your efforts, all you're doing here is stating what you want and asking for code to get your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print df
#       15/12/2015  15/11/2015  15/10/2015
#Stock                                    
#AA             10          11          11
#BB             20          10           8
#CC             30          33          26
#DD             40          80          60

print df1
#       15/12/2015  15/11/2015  15/10/2015
#Stock                                    
#AA              2          11          22
#BB              4          14          33
#CC              3          12          30
#DD              5          16          40
```

```
#add boolean columns to df1 from df
df1['bool1'] = df['15/12/2015'] < df['15/11/2015']
df1['bool2'] = df['15/11/2015'] < df['15/10/2015']
print df1
#       15/12/2015  15/11/2015  15/10/2015  bool1  bool2
#Stock                                                  
#AA              2          11          22   True  False
#BB              4          14          33  False  False
#CC              3          12          30   True  False
#DD              5          16          40   True  False

#remove column 15/10/2015, add columns to index
df1 = df1.drop(['15/10/2015'], axis = 1)
df1 = df1.set_index(['bool1', 'bool2'], append=True)
print df1
#                   15/12/2015  15/11/2015
#Stock bool1 bool2                        
#AA    True  False           2          11
#BB    False False           4          14
#CC    True  False           3          12
#DD    True  False           5          16
```

```
#stack df1 by level 0
df1 = df1.stack(0).reset_index(name='values').rename(columns={'level_3':'dates'})

#column bool from bool1 and bool2 by dates
df1['bool'] = df1.bool1.where(df1['dates'].str.contains('15/12/2015'), df1.bool2) 
df1 = df1.drop(['bool1', 'bool2'], axis = 1)
#change order
print df1[['Stock', 'dates', 'bool', 'values']]
#  Stock       dates   bool  values
#0    AA  15/12/2015   True       2
#1    AA  15/11/2015  False      11
#2    BB  15/12/2015  False       4
#3    BB  15/11/2015  False      14
#4    CC  15/12/2015   True       3
#5    CC  15/11/2015  False      12
#6    DD  15/12/2015   True       5
#7    DD  15/11/2015  False      16
```

Comment: Wow thanks. Hopefully i can get this running on a loop and will save so much work